# Efficient way of reshaping a ndarray using sliding window without to use too much memory

Tags: multidimensional-array, memory-leaks, reshape, sliding-window, tf.data.dataset

I have to reshape a ndarray of [17205, 21] as [17011, 96, 100, 21] by applying two sliding windows to it.

```
In: arr
Out: [[ 8.  0.  0. -0.  0.  0.  8.  8.  0.  0.  0.  0.  8.  7.  6.  9.  9.  1.
   1.  1.  2.]
 [ 8.  0.  0. -0.  0.  0.  8.  8.  0.  0.  0.  0.  8.  7.  5.  9.  8.  2.
   1.  1.  2.]
.
.
.
 [ 8.  0.  0. -0.  0.  0.  8.  8.  0.  0.  0.  0.  8.  7.  5.  9.  8.  3.
   1.  1.  2.]]
```

My solution was to apply sliding windows to it two times.
Then I apply the following method two times:

```
def separate_multi(sequences, n_steps):
    X = list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
       # find the end of this pattern
       end_ix = i + n_steps
       # check if we are beyond the dataset
       if end_ix > len(sequences):
           break
            # gather input and output parts of the pattern
       seq_x = sequences[i:end_ix, :]           
       X.append(seq_x)
       return np.array(X)
```

Giving the shape of `[17106, 100, 21]` and then once again with `n_step=96`, giving the shape of `[17011, 96, 100, 21]`.

DRAWBACK: It stores the whole data in the memory which gives an error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 24.3 GiB for an array with shape (17011, 96, 100, 20) and data type float64
```

A possible solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
df = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df)
df = df.window(100, shift=1, stride=1, drop_remainder=True)
df = df.window(96, shift=1, stride=1, drop_remainder=True)
```

However, it doesn't give me the desired output since "it produces a dataset of nested windows", as it is said [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L2004-L2083).

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution to my question:

The main problem wasn't to reshape the data in two steps, but actually the size of the objects I was forming by reshaping the data. Therefore, the solution was to break down the input array into pieces. For that aim I've design the following function:

```
def split_chunks(sequence, chunk=3000):
    list_seq = []
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        if (i+1)*chunk > len(sequence):
            seq = sequence[i*chunk:-1, :]
            list_seq.append(seq)
            break
        else:
            seq = sequence[i*chunk:(i+1)*chunk, :]
            list_seq.append(seq)
    return list_seq
```

And then reshape each array inside the `list_seq`. Another option is the NumPy method `np.split()`, however, my function is 9 times faster than this one.